# Exclude row when the value in column B is present somewhere (in another row) in column C

Tags: sql

As the title describes I'm looking for a way to exclude the entire row from my select clause when the value in column B of this row is present anywhere in column C of the same table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
col_a,
col_b,
col_c
FROM table

WHERE col_b NOT IN (SELECT col_c FROM table)
```

Should do it.